# Set images as marker doesn't load in mapview

Tags: android, android-maps

I have mapview that shows the current location and a marker. When I used marker from drawable folder (example: `R.drawable.marker`), the marker load perfectly but, in my case, I want to put my certain image as marker. Let's say the path of my image is `"/mnt/sdcard/ppbfolder/...jpg"`

I use this code

```
String imgpath="/mnt/sdcard/ppbfolder/...jpg";
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), imgpath);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
overlayitem.setMarker(drawable);
```

The code didn't display the picture, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Call populate() on your `ItemizedOverlay`?